# Microcontroller 8051 with matrix keyboard and LED display

Tags: keyboard, led, keil, 8051

I have such a program, it works. I get the number from pressed button on the LED display. But I need to change this program so it shows the last 2 pressed numbers on the display, when I press * or #.
For example, I press '1 2 3 4 5 #'. On the display I see only two last numbers '4 5'. How can I do this?

```
#include <REGX52.h>
#define SEG P1
#define keypad P2

sbit r1 = P2^0; 
sbit r2 = P2^1; 
sbit r3 = P2^2; 
sbit r4 = P2^3; 

sbit c1 = P2^4; 
sbit c2 = P2^5; 
sbit c3 = P2^6; 
sbit c4 = P3^7;

void scan(void);

unsigned int Display[12] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x9};

void main(void)
{
while(1)
{
    scan();
}
}

void scan(void){
r1=0;
r2=r3=r4=1;

if(c1==0)
{
    while(c1==0){
        P1=Display[1];
    }
}
    if(c2==0)
    {
        while(c2==0){
            P1=Display[2];
}
}
    if(c3==0)
{
    while(c3==0){
        P1=Display[3];
    }
}
r2=0;
r1=r3=r4=1;
if(c1==0)
{
    while(c1==0){
        P1=Display[4];
    }
}
if(c2==0)
    {
        while(c2==0){
            P1=Display[5];
}
}
    if(c3==0)
{
    while(c3==0){
        P1=Display[6];
    }
}
r3=0;
r1=r2=r4=1;
if(c1==0)
{
    while(c1==0){
        P1=Display[7];
    }
}
if(c2==0)
    {
        while(c2==0){
            P1=Display[8];
}
}
    if(c3==0)
{
    while(c3==0){
        P1=Display[9];
    }
}
r4=0;
r1=r2=r3=1;
if(c2==0)
{
    while(c2==0){
        P1=Display[0];
}
    }
```

[image: schema]

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int last_two_buttons[2] = {0x0, 0x0}; /* array of 2 elements to remember the last two buttons pressed. */

unsigned int update_display = 0; //flag to indicate if LED display needs to be updated.
```

Now, Instead of assigning P1 = Display[x] for each of the button pressed, you simply remember/store that button pressed in this array as follows:

```
last_two_buttons[0] = last_two_buttons[1]; 
last_two_buttons[1] = Display[x]; //x here indicates the button pressed, the same way as you have been using in your code.
```

Now, enhance the scan() to detect the * and the # buttons.

```
r4=0;
r1=r2=r3=1;
if(c1==0)
{
    while(c1==0){
        update_display = 1; // * button pressed
}

if(c3==0)
{
    while(c3==0){
        update_display = 1; // # button pressed
}

if(update_display)
{

    P1 = last_two_buttons[0] <<4 + last_two_buttons[1];
    update_display = 0; //reset the variables for next scan.
    last_two_buttons[0] = 0; 
    last_two_buttons[1] = 0;

}
```

The assumption here is that, if the user presses only one button, say 5# then, we will be displaying 0 and 5 as the last two pressed buttons.

Hope this helps.